# How to give orginal hex code color in Principle Volume?

Tags: shader-nodes

Here The Tornado is showing different color from the sand even though i applied the same hex code. I used Principle Volume for the tornado and i gave the hex code of the sand but the tornado appears to be dark. I didnt add any light.I need the tornado to be as same colour as the sand. CAn ANyone help?

And If I add the Light the tornado goes completely transparent as shown in the first image

[image]

[image]